# Convert a comma seperated string to an array to use in bash, append a value, sort the array, then convert back to string to store in the database

Tags: bash, sqlite

EDIT: OK, I've been convinced that an array is not a good idea!

```
#!/bin/bash
# /bin/sh cannot be used with this script as "=~" is bash only
[snip]
sqlite $database "create table ports (port TEXT PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, comment TEXT);"  # name = short name, i.e. "https"
[snip]
getports=$(sqlite $database "SELECT * FROM $ports ORDER BY port ASC";)
if [[ -z ${getports[@]} ]]; then
 fail "No ports mapped, set up traefik first!"
fi
APPRISE_API_PORT=$(whiptail --inputbox --title "API Port" "Set the port to call the Apprise API on \nCurrently used ports: \n${getports[@]}" 20 60 "8000" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)  # Default of port 8000
exitstatus=$?
if [ $exitstatus = "0" ]; then
  if [ -z "$APPRISE_API_PORT" ]; then
    fail "Entry was blank - please set the port. You cannot leave this blank!"
  else
    if [[ "${array[*]}" =~ "$APPRISE_API_PORT" ]]; then
    fail "Port already in use - please select an unused port"
    sqlite variables.db "insert into settings (name,value,comment) values ('$APPRISE_API_PORT', 'apprise', 'The Apprise API port');" 
  fi
else
echo "User cancelled"
fi
[snip]
```

Note: bash variables are mapped, fail is a function, and code for replacing values in the docker-compose.yml file etc all are in the snipped sections.

Project can be viewed at https://github.com/animeai/docker-compose/tree/0.1-testing

Original question:

Bash newbie here - please be gentle!

This necessary is due to an sqlite deficiency that won't allow the storage of arrays (to my knowledge - correct me if I'm wrong!). The database table has 3 columns, "name" (i.e. "https"), "value", and "comment" - all are text strings.

```
#!/bin/bash
ports=$(sqlite database.db "SELECT value FROM settings WHERE name = 'USED_PORTS'";)  # Returns "80,443,8000,8080,9999"
[convert $ports to array]  # Need help with this!
ports+=("1234")  # Append port "1234" to array
[sort array low to high]  # Need help with this!
[convert $ports array to string]  # Need help with this - string should now read "80,443,1234,8000,8080,9999"
sqlite database.db "UPDATE settings set value = '$ports' where name = 'USED_PORTS';  # Insert back into the database
```

Would it be simpler to just create a new table in the database called something like portsused (name, port, comment) and use "SELECT port from portsused" from the table and order by value ascending? I would prefer a single database entry though to simplify future coding as the number of ports could grow quite large with enough apps running. After getting this basic function working, I would be doing things like searching the array when adding a new port to make sure there are no conflicts.

Comment: It will be simpler to refine your database schema.

Comment: @Toto Could you be more specific? This database is a simple variables store with global "settings" and individual docker application settings. More info (and very alpha and completely untested so far) https://github.com/animeai/docker-compose/tree/0.1-testing. Currently the main install.sh and setup.sh for adguardhome and airsonic-advanced are set up, but I want to avoid port clashes by using a variable for necessary mapped ports.

Comment: NEVER store list of data in a single field.

Comment: @Toto Fair! I'll go with a fresh table in the db. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why do you need an array? Why cant you just iterate and manipulate ports as a space separated list and either store the space separated list in the database or use tr to translate spaces to commas and vice versa?

Comment: @davidgo Yeah, I've been persuaded otherwise! I edited the original question to show my solution

Answer (score 0):

I'm not encouraging you to do this, obviously the db-specific advice is crucial here.

However, a shell method to achieve your goal to insert 1234 in its place in a csv string:

```sh
row="80,443,8000,8080,9999"
new=$(echo "1234,$row" | tr , '\n' | sort -n | paste -sd,)
declare -p row new
```

outputs

```
declare -- row="80,443,8000,8080,9999"
declare -- new="80,443,1234,8000,8080,9999"
```